# Know if a class property is used in a class function

Tags: java

Using reflections in Java permits me to know information about parameters and returned type of every class function, however I would like to know if exists a way to know if a property is used in a function (in the same class):

```
public class ClassExample {
    private String propertyExample;

    public void function1() {
       ...
    }

    public void function2() {
       ...
       propertyExample = "";
       ...
    }

    public Integer function3 (String parameter) {
       ...
       propertyExample = parameter;
       ...
    }   
  }
```

In this case, I need to know that **propertyExample** is used in **function2** and **function3**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783015/how-to-get-the-object-reference-of-a-field-of-an-object-using-reflection

Comment: That is not a capability of reflection.  You would have to instrument the bytecode to be able to detect that.

Comment: Is there a specific purpose? Otherwise, the obvious solution is that you could always just return, for example, a boolean (changed = true) from the function as soon as you change propertyExample. Just trying to understand the problem with more details.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Hi Michael, but it is not possible because may exist functions that returns its "own values".

Comment: Google has an open-source project called [kythe](https://www.kythe.io/) which indexes code (e.g. to allow you to find where a symbol is used). It supports Java. Never used it myself, but it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is unfortunately not possible without parsing the byte code.

Comment: There might be a solution to your problem anyway :) As others pointed out, try to explain the reason you need this, and maybe we can think of a way to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: read the full answer before judging it.**

Marking the field `final` will allow the compiler to warn you that the field is used (assigned).

```
public class ClassExample {
    private static final String propertyExample;

    public void function1() {
       ...
    }

    public void function2() {
       ...
       propertyExample = ""; //<-- compiler tells you that propertyExample is used (assigned)
       ...
    }

    public Integer function3 (String parameter) {
       ...
       propertyExample = parameter; //<-- compiler tells you that propertyExample is used (assigned)
       ...
    }
}
```

Although my answer provides a solution to your question, I'm sure it's not in the way you would expect it. As Edvin Syse said, it's not possible without parsing the byte code.

However, there's an underlying problem to this question that we are not aware of. You only showed us the solution you thought could resolve it. If you share the real problem with us, the SO community may be more useful for you and be able to help you finding an accurate solution to your problem (maybe :-)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not add the clause final to the property I need to change "the properties". On the other hand, where have I written a solution to the problem? I have written a "dummy use case" because "this problem" is a small part of a functionality that I want to do.

Comment: @doctore Why do you want to know if/when/how much a class attribute is used in the code ? It's not a common requirement for a software feature.
The only cases I see (from my limited point of view) is that you are developing some static code analyzer, profiler, ...